# InflateException and IllegalStateException while using fragments for a customised list

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android app which generates two lists on HomeActivity using Fragment and listView and it is also customised for using NavigationViewer for menu.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {


    PackageManager packageManager;
    ListView apkList,l;
    ImageView i;
    int c=0,sys=1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
                Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft=fm.beginTransaction();
        Fragment1 f1=new Fragment1();
        Fragment2 f2=new Fragment2();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_2,f2);
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_1,f1);
        ft.commit();


    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify img parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.themes) {
            Intent i1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);

        } else if (id == R.id.settings) {
            Intent i1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(i1);
        } else if (id == R.id.share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.send) {

        } else if (id == R.id.rating) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Fragment1:

```
public class Fragment1 extends ListFragment {
 PackageManager pm;
    ListView apList;
    int c = 1;

    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Fragment1() {

    }


    public static Fragment1 newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        Fragment1 fragment = new Fragment1();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

        apList=(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<PackageInfo> packageList = pm
                .getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

        List<PackageInfo> packageList1 = new ArrayList<PackageInfo>();

        for (PackageInfo pi : packageList) {
            boolean b = isSystemPackage(pi);
            if (!b) {
                packageList1.add(pi);
            }

        }

        apList.setAdapter(new ApkAdapter(this, packageList1, pm, c));

    }
    private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
        if((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & (ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM|ApplicationInfo.FLAG_UPDATED_SYSTEM_APP)) >0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
 }
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_1, container, false);
    }

    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {

        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Fragment 2:

```
public class Fragment2 extends ListFragment {
    int c=0;
    String str[]= {"Wifi","Bluetooth"};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle s) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, vg, false);

    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("Wifi");
    l.add("Bluetooth");
    ApkAdapter ad = new ApkAdapter(this,l ,c);
    setListAdapter(ad);
    return view;
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle s) {
        ListView l1;
        l1=(ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        List<String> l=new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("Wifi");
        l.add("Bluetooth");
        ApkAdapter ad=new ApkAdapter(this,l,c);
        l1.setAdapter(ad);

    }
}
```

ApkAdapter :

```
public class ApkAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<PackageInfo> packageList;
    List<String> s1;
    Fragment1 context;
    Fragment2 context1;
    PackageManager packageManager;
    Switch s;

    int c;
    String appName;
    String str[];
    int img[]={R.drawable.wifi,R.drawable.bluetooth};
    public ApkAdapter(Fragment1 context, List<PackageInfo> packageList,
                      PackageManager packageManager, int c) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.packageList = packageList;
        this.packageManager = packageManager;
        this.c=c;
    }
    public ApkAdapter(Fragment2 context,List<String> s,int c)
    {
        super();
        this.context1=context;
        this.s1=s;
        this.c=c;
    }
    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView apkName;
        ImageView i;

    }

    public int getCount() {
        if (c == 1) {
            return packageList.size();
        }
        else if(c==0)
        {
            return str.length;
        }
        else return 0;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        if(c==1){
            return packageList.get(position);
        }
        else
            return position;
    }


    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder,h1;
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        LayoutInflater inflater1 = context1.getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (convertView == null) {
            if(c==0) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.apklist_item, null);
            }
            else if(c==1)
            {
                convertView = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.apklist_item, null);
            }
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.apkName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.appname);
            holder.i=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
try{
        if(c==0) {
            int j = 0;
            while (j < 2) {
                int ser=(Integer) getItem(position);
                appName=s1.get(ser);
                Drawable dr = context.getResources().getDrawable(img[j]);
                dr.setBounds(0,0,10,10);
                resize(dr);
                holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img[j], 0, 0, 0);
                holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(3);
                holder.apkName.setText("\n" + "  " + appName);
                j++;
            }
        }
        else if(c==1) {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = (PackageInfo) getItem(position);
            Drawable appIcon = packageManager
                    .getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.applicationInfo);
            appName = packageManager.getApplicationLabel(
                    packageInfo.applicationInfo).toString();
            appIcon.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
            holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawables(appIcon, null, null, null);
            holder.apkName.setCompoundDrawablePadding(25);
            holder.apkName.setText("\n" + "  " + appName);
        }
    holder.i.setScaleY(0.5f);
         holder.i.setImageResource(R.drawable.images);
     }
     catch(Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
        return convertView;
    }
    public Drawable resize(Drawable i)
    {
        Bitmap b=((BitmapDrawable)i).getBitmap();
        Bitmap br=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b,10,10,false);
        return new BitmapDrawable(Resources.getSystem(),br);
    }
}
```

There is one more AppData Class which has `getPackageInfo()` and `setPackageInfo()` methods.

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
        android:name="com.example.sardwal.applock.Fragment2"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2" />
    <fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
        android:name="com.example.sardwal.applock.Fragment1"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment_1.xml and fragment_2.xml have listView and TextView while former is using frameLayout, latter is using linear.Both having an id tag set to android:idlist

apklist_item.xml :
 It has a textview and ImageView.
Can't put their code because of word limit. I suppose it will not make any difference.

I am getting following exceptions in logcat and don't know how to resolve them:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.sardwal.applock, PID: 21919
                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sardwal.applock/com.example.sardwal.applock.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2584)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
                                                       at com.example.sardwal.applock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6583)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1114)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2531)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
                                                    Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class fragment
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:782)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:971)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:831)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                                                       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
                                                       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
                                                       at com.example.sardwal.applock.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44) 
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6583) 
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1114) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2531) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2666) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1493) 
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5769) 
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Apart from this, recently when i ran same code on my lenovo device, i got following errors on logcat Error:

```
 E/AppOnlineConfigurationUpdateTask: Get app configuration fail. Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=/reaper/server/appparams
                                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=/reaper/server/appparams
                                                                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:603)
                                                                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:299)
                                                                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:601)
                                                                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:519)
                                                                       at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:497)
                                                                       at com.lenovo.lps.reaper.sdk.i.b.a(Unknown)
                                                                       at com.lenovo.lps.reaper.sdk.i.a.run(Unknown)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

E/ConfigurationUpdateTask: Same stuff IllegalStateException 

 E/SurfaceFlinger: strok layer name=none

 E/EventReportHandler: Same stuff IllegalStateException

 E/SurfaceFlinger: strok layer name=none

 E/WifiTrafficPoller: TRAFFIC_STATS_POLL true Token 1540 num clients 10
 E/WifiTrafficPoller:  packet count Tx=1476881 Rx=1685658
 E/InputMethodManagerService: Ignoring updateSystemUiLocked due to an invalid token. uid:1000 token:null
 E/SwitchMobileDataTile: mobile data not ready or disabled
 E/InputDispatcher: channel 'f377d75  (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
 E/MountService: setDefaultPath new path=/storage/emulated/0
```

I have stuck into these errors and not getting how to resolve them.
Thanks

Comment: reformatted the code

Answer (score 1):

The app crashes, because you are looking for your list in the onCreate method in the Fragments. You should use something like this in the fragments:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) { ListView l1;
    l1=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    List<String> l=new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("Wifi");
    l.add("Bluetooth");
    ApkAdapter ad=new ApkAdapter(this,l,c);
    l1.setAdapter(ad);}
```

This is called after the Fragment's onCreateView method, so your layout for the Fragment will be set and you won't be looking for a null ListView.

Comment: It's still giving that InflateException  although Nullpointerexception os resolved....

Answer (score 0):

In your case in order to work you must the following:
fragment 1 xml should look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit:** 
   Fragment 2 xml should be almost the same:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The creation of the fragment should be the same: 
onCreate is from the Activity of course.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment1 f1 = new Fragment1();
    Fragment2 f2 = new Fragment2();

    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_1, f1);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_2, f2);

    ft.commit();
}
```

Next in onCreateView you should have something like that:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup vg, Bundle s) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_2, vg, false);

        List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
        l.add("Wifi");
        l.add("Bluetooth");
        ApkAdapter ad = //choose whichever constructor you want.
        setListAdapter(ad);
        return view;
    }
```

Activity layout xml should look like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
        android:name="com.example.atstanescu.myapplication.Fragment1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_2" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
        android:name="com.example.atstanescu.myapplication.Fragment2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_1" />
</LinearLayout>

One additional note, your adapter looks really buggy. I needed to reduce it a lot to see some issues. For example you check for c==0 and c==1 but what happens if you have 2, 3.
```

Comment: Thanks, i haven'et  checked c's case , i thnk it will be resolved if i set it to 1 initially rather than that increment.

Comment: Yeah, let me if it helped. In my case I could see some dummy data.

Comment: It's still giving InflateException at MainActivity :44 i. e., setContentView()

Comment: fragment 1 and 2 xmls should both have this android:list, because of your ListFragment extension and also because instead of having FrameLayout you added the fragment directly. I edited my answer.

Comment: It has resolved one of listView exceptions but RuntimeException :InflateException is still not resolved

Comment: If it is the same exception than you are doing something wrong, in my case there is no such thing. Use the same layout with the android:list for both and see if you are still getting it.

Comment: Check if you are not getting it from the adapter, there are also some potential inflation issues.

Comment: Yeah,  InflateException at MainActivity:44

Comment: Use the debugger because and see why you have it because it seems that you are missing some view, probably the Floating widget. The problem you had initially with the fragment is fixed.

Comment: Also you missed to show us(or I least I did not see) where you integrate the fragments to the activity main xml.

Comment: I have put activity main. Xml and content_main. Xml

Comment: Fragments are integrated in content_main,  if i have to do anything else too?